# mysql select for update concurency issues

Tags: mysql

We have an table bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE usable (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key ,
device VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
key1 VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
key2 VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
create unique index uidx_usable on usable (key1);

CREATE TABLE used
(
usedid bigint(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
devid VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
key1 VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL ,
key2 VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL '
created_time timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
create unique index uidx_used on used (key1);
create unique index uidx_used_deviceid on used (devid);
```

1. select 1 record from usable table wih muti-thread.
2. insert into record to used table.
3. delete this record from usable table.

my work goes here:

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM usable WHERE device = 555 order by rand() limit 1 FOR UPDATE;
insert into used (key1, key2) values (key1, key2 from step 1 select result);
delete from usable where id = (id from step 1 select result);
COMMIT
```

The  tables are in InnoDB engine. AutoCommit is set to ON in the global variables.

There is no problem for just one thread, about 100ms with these three sql cmds. Is there solution to improve it? 
but, thread begin to hang up when 100 QPS.
How to congfirm transaction worked?
How to improve QPS

(0.7~5ms) SELECT ; (47ms~250ms) insert ; (48ms~250ms) delete
why insert and delete need large time? how to tune insert and delete sql?

Comment: Please, refrain of using words like 'urgent' , 'emergency', ... I can understand you may feel frustrated because your problem keep your brain burning but those words won't help.

Comment: Please, state clearly the error you get.

Comment: isnt it much more logical to combine both tables into a single `parts` table  and add a `used` tinyiny (boolean) column instead of having to move stuff around all the time ?

Comment: The senaro is : 1. a client customer request one usable key1 from server, and  key1(which is permanent) is allocate to this customer. And next time, if customer request again, we will just return key1 in used table.   So ,we need used table to mark the allocated key.

Comment: `order by rand() limit 1 FOR UPDATE` is unlikely to do good things... it seems likely to lock a large number of rows.

Comment: is there alternative solution for  ‘order by rand() limit 1 FOR UPDATE’

Comment: why three sql exced time 100ms,  it's too large,